# How can I uninstall NetBeans?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, netbeans

Yesterday,

I installed netbeans by downloading it from website

I ran the .sh file which installed it

Now i want to remove it

It does not show in the installed panel in ubuntu software center

what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look *uninstall.sh* for your installed tool like below:

```
find / -name uninstall.sh
```

cd /to/path: and execute command:

```
 ./uninstall.sh
```

Or

```
sudo /opt/netbeans-x.x/uninstall.sh --javahome /opt/jdk1.x.0_x/
```